# Networking between KVM VM and docker container on same host

Tags: linux-networking, docker, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, debian-stretch

On a Debian-Stretch host (connected to physical LAN) I have a new docker installation (v18.09) with one database container (port mapped to the host) and I run KVM/libvirt with some Debian-Stretch VMs. I can access the docker container and the VMs from the LAN (depending on the configuration trough SSH tunnel or direct) but I am struggling to access the docker container from the VMs.

[image]

```
# brctl show
bridge name         bridge id           STP enabled interfaces
br-f9f3ccd64037     8000.0242b3ebe3a0   no      
docker0             8000.024241f39b89   no      veth35454ac
virbr0              8000.525400566522   yes     virbr0-nic
```

After reading for days, I found one very compelling solution in this post [Docker and KVM with a bridge](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.summer.co.at%2Fpost%2F2018%2F03%2F15_docker_birdge%2F) ([original](https://www.summer.co.at/post/2018/03/15_docker_birdge/)) that I did not get to work. The solution suggest to initiate docker with a one-line config daemon.json code to use the KVM "default" bridge. How nice would that be! Is there any hope?

I tried two different configurations for networking between the KVM VMs. In both cases the communication between the VMs and to the LAN+router+cloud is flawless but I just don't know how to get over the fence - to the greener grass... :)

Conf 1 - KVM default bridge with NAT: I can ssh to the Debian host and access the docker container port but is there a setup with a direct route?

Conf 2 - macvtap adapter in Bridge mode to the LAN: I can not ping the host LAN IP from the VM although both are connected to the same router. Response from the VM itself is `Destination Host Unreachable`. Any thought why?

Would it be better to run the docker daemon in a separate VM rather than directly on the Debian host? This way both, the container and the VM, could access the KVM default bridge. But I thought it is kinda strange to run docker in a VM on a KVM host.

Any clear guidance would be appreciated!

Btw, the bridge `br-f9f3ccd64037` is a user-defined bridge I created with docker for future inter-container communication. It is not used.

**Update:**

I just realized that with the first configuration I can simply connect to the docker container by its IP address (172.17.0.2) from the VM guests.

My initial setup was the second configuration because I wanted to RDP into the VMs, which is easier since the macvtap driver connects the VMs directly to the LAN and no SSH link is needed. That's when I could not reach the container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was as simple as stated in the linked article. I am not sure why my configuration did not change the first time I restarted the docker daemon.

After I found evidence in the [Docker daemon documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) for the bridge argument in daemon.json, I gave it another try and the docker daemon picked up the KVM default bridge on startup.

First I created the configuration file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` as suggested in the documentation with the following content (the iptables line may not even be needed):

```
{
"bridge": "virbr0",
"iptables": false
}
```

all that was needed was:

```
docker stop mysql
systemctl stop docker
systemctl start docker
docker start mysql
```

And the existing docker container was running on the KVM bridge. The IP address of the container can be checked with:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' mysql
192.168.122.2
```

I am not sure if I can remove the docker0 bridge now, but the container is listed under virbr0 together with the three VMs.

```
brctl show
bridge name bridge id           STP enabled interfaces
docker0     8000.024241f39b89   no      
virbr0      8000.068ff2a4a56e   yes         veth2abcff1
                                            virbr0-nic
                                            vnet0
                                            vnet1
                                            vnet2
```

Comment: I tried this but did not work after restart as I wanted docker containers to have main host's IP, not get new one from network like the VMs do. There was some more info here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=233727. Best thing I can do is start docker after boot completes, not as service in systemd - then everything works for me, but isn't ideal.

Comment: I just setup another Debian box and it worked again for me. Best to check the configuration with `docker network inspect bridge`. If the json-config file does not work than it may be because the docs state: "Note: You cannot set options in daemon.json that have already been set on daemon startup as a flag."

Answer (score 3):

When I read the question, I was looking to see if there was a way to connect `virbr0` to a Docker network. The image below is my modification of what I think was being asked:

[image]

If that is the case, the answer is to use a `macvlan` network, which allows you to attach a docker network directly to a host device. So something like the following would get you what you want:

`docker network create --driver=macvlan --subnet=192.168.0.0/16 -o parent=virbr0 mynet`

Answer (score 2):

I'm used to implement that using the following setup :

- I create a `br0` bridge with the physical nic inside
- kvm machines are connected on the bridge using qemu xml config snippet below

```
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:a9:28:0a'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

- docker stacks are all running the same : I reserve a public routable IP for each stack. I connect this public IP to the bridge `br0` using the opensvc service config snippet below.

  - the `[ip#0]` section tells that we want the ip `1.2.3.4` configured into the container with resource id `container#0` which is a docker google/pause, and connected to bridge `br0`
  - all other dockers in the stack herit network config from `container#0` due to config `netns = container#0` in the docker declaration
  - when the opensvc service starts, the network setup is done by the agent, producing all the commands reported in the logs below

**opensvc service configuration**

```
[DEFAULT]
docker_daemon_args = --log-opt max-size=1m --storage-driver=zfs --iptables=false
docker_data_dir = /{env.base_dir}/docker
env = PRD
nodes = srv1.acme.com srv2.acme.com
orchestrate = start
id = 4958b24d-4d0f-4c30-71d2-bb820e043a5d

[fs#1]
dev = {env.pool}/{namespace}-{svcname}
mnt = {env.base_dir}
mnt_opt = rw,xattr,acl
type = zfs

[fs#2]
dev = {env.pool}/{namespace}-{svcname}/docker
mnt = {env.base_dir}/docker
mnt_opt = rw,xattr,acl
type = zfs

[fs#3]
dev = {env.pool}/{namespace}-{svcname}/data
mnt = {env.base_dir}/data
mnt_opt = rw,xattr,acl
type = zfs

[ip#0]
netns = container#0
ipdev = br0
ipname = 1.2.3.4
netmask = 255.255.255.224
gateway = 1.2.3.1
type = netns

[container#0]
hostname = {svcname}
image = google/pause
rm = true
run_command = /bin/sh
type = docker

[container#mysvc]
image = mysvc/mysvc:4.1.3
netns = container#0
run_args = -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    -v {env.base_dir}/data/mysvc:/home/mysvc/server/data
type = docker

[env]
base_dir = /srv/{namespace}-{svcname}
pool = data
```

**startup log**

```
2019-01-04 11:27:14,617 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.ip#0 - INFO - checking 1.2.3.4 availability
2019-01-04 11:27:18,565 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.fs#1 - INFO - mount -t zfs -o rw,xattr,acl data/appprd-mysvc /srv/appprd-mysvc
2019-01-04 11:27:18,877 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.fs#2 - INFO - mount -t zfs -o rw,xattr,acl data/appprd-mysvc/docker /srv/appprd-mysvc/docker
2019-01-04 11:27:19,106 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.fs#3 - INFO - mount -t zfs -o rw,xattr,acl data/appprd-mysvc/data /srv/appprd-mysvc/data
2019-01-04 11:27:19,643 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc - INFO - starting docker daemon
2019-01-04 11:27:19,644 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc - INFO - dockerd -H unix:///var/lib/opensvc/namespaces/appprd/services/mysvc/docker.sock --data-root //srv/appprd-mysvc/docker -p /var/lib/opensvc/namespaces/appprd/services/mysvc/docker.pid --exec-root /var/lib/opensvc/namespaces/appprd/services/mysvc/docker_exec --log-opt max-size=1m --storage-driver=zfs --iptables=false --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs
2019-01-04 11:27:24,669 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.container#0 - INFO - docker -H unix:///var/lib/opensvc/namespaces/appprd/services/mysvc/docker.sock run --name=appprd..mysvc.container.0 --detach --hostname mysvc --net=none --cgroup-parent /opensvc.slice/appprd.slice/mysvc.slice/container.slice/container.0.slice google/pause /bin/sh
2019-01-04 11:27:30,965 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.container#0 - INFO - output:
2019-01-04 11:27:30,965 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.container#0 - INFO - f790e192b5313d7c3450cb257d075620f40c2bad3d69d52c8794eccfe954f250
2019-01-04 11:27:30,987 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.container#0 - INFO - wait for up status
2019-01-04 11:27:31,031 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.container#0 - INFO - wait for container operational
2019-01-04 11:27:31,186 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.ip#0 - INFO - bridge mode
2019-01-04 11:27:31,268 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.ip#0 - INFO - /sbin/ip link add name veth0pl20321 mtu 1500 type veth peer name veth0pg20321 mtu 1500
2019-01-04 11:27:31,273 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.ip#0 - INFO - /sbin/ip link set veth0pl20321 master br0
2019-01-04 11:27:31,277 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.ip#0 - INFO - /sbin/ip link set veth0pl20321 up
2019-01-04 11:27:31,281 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.ip#0 - INFO - /sbin/ip link set veth0pg20321 netns 20321
2019-01-04 11:27:31,320 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.ip#0 - INFO - /usr/bin/nsenter --net=/var/lib/opensvc/namespaces/appprd/services/mysvc/docker_exec/netns/fc2fa9b2eaa4 ip link set veth0pg20321 name eth0
2019-01-04 11:27:31,356 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.ip#0 - INFO - /usr/bin/nsenter --net=/var/lib/opensvc/namespaces/appprd/services/mysvc/docker_exec/netns/fc2fa9b2eaa4 ip addr add 1.2.3.4/27 dev eth0
2019-01-04 11:27:31,362 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.ip#0 - INFO - /usr/bin/nsenter --net=/var/lib/opensvc/namespaces/appprd/services/mysvc/docker_exec/netns/fc2fa9b2eaa4 ip link set eth0 up
2019-01-04 11:27:31,372 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.ip#0 - INFO - /usr/bin/nsenter --net=/var/lib/opensvc/namespaces/appprd/services/mysvc/docker_exec/netns/fc2fa9b2eaa4 ip route replace default via 1.2.3.1
2019-01-04 11:27:31,375 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.ip#0 - INFO - /usr/bin/nsenter --net=/var/lib/opensvc/namespaces/appprd/services/mysvc/docker_exec/netns/fc2fa9b2eaa4 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/opensvc/lib/arp.py eth0 1.2.3.4
2019-01-04 11:27:32,534 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.container#mysvc - INFO - docker -H unix:///var/lib/opensvc/namespaces/appprd/services/mysvc/docker.sock run --name=appprd..mysvc.container.mysvc -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro -v /srv/appprd-mysvc/data/mysvc:/home/mysvc/server/data --detach --net=container:appprd..mysvc.container.0 --cgroup-parent /opensvc.slice/appprd.slice/mysvc.slice/container.slice/container.mysvc.slice mysvc/mysvc:4.1.3
2019-01-04 11:27:37,776 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.container#mysvc - INFO - output:
2019-01-04 11:27:37,777 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.container#mysvc - INFO - 1616cade9257d0616346841c3e9f0d639a9306e1af6fd750fe70e17903a11011
2019-01-04 11:27:37,797 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.container#mysvc - INFO - wait for up status
2019-01-04 11:27:37,833 - srv1.acme.com.appprd.mysvc.container#mysvc - INFO - wait for container operational
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am not familiar with opensvc and I will have to chew on your suggestion for a while... Also, for a connection between KVM and docker would I need a physical nic connected to the bridge?? Apart from the nic is your bridge any different than the KVM default bridge virbr0?

Comment: you should not need a physical nic in the bridge in your case. as far as I know, no difference with kvm virbr0. you may have missed it, but there is no need for docker & iptables magic stuff in my setup. easy to troubleshoot !

Comment: Looking at OpenSVC, I just feel I am cracking a nut with a sledgehammer... even though it is really interesting...